# Spark Group By Key to (String, Iterable<String>)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to group urldata by key where the values would be string

Sample Data :

```
url_3 url_2
url_3 url_2
url_3 url_1
url_4 url_3
url_4 url_1
```

Expected result:

```
(url_3,(url_2,url_1))
(url_4,(url_3,url_1))
```

1) Load the urldata:

```
Dataset<String> lines = spark.read()
    .textFile("C:/Users/91984/workspace/myApp/src/test/resources/in/urldata.txt");
```

2) Split the dataset using space

```
Encoder<Tuple2<String, String>> encoder2 = 
    Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.STRING());
Dataset<Tuple2<String, String>> tupleRDD = lines.map(f->{
    Tuple2<String, String> m = 
        new Tuple2<String, String>(f.split(" ")[0], f.split(" ")[1]);
    return m;
},encoder2);
```

3) Used groupbyKey to group the tupleRDD datsebase on key

```
KeyValueGroupedDataset<String, Tuple2<String, String>> keygrpDS = 
    tupleRDD.groupByKey(f->f._1, Encoders.STRING());
```

Can someone explain me why groupByKey at step 3 is returning  `KeyValueGroupedDataset<String, Tuple2<String, String>>` instead of `KeyValueGroupedDataset<String, Iterable<String>>` and what will be the change to be done to get the expected results.

Comment: please accept the answer as correct or state any issues if you still are facing.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way it works with datasets in spark. When you have a dataset of type `Dataset<T>`, you can group it by some mapping function that takes an object of type T and returns an object of type K (the key). What you get is a `KeyValueGroupedDataset<K,T>` on which you can call an aggregation function (See [the javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.html)). In your case, you could use `mapGroups` to which you can provide a function that maps a key `K` and an iterable `Iterable<T>` to a new object R of your choosing. If it helps, in your code, T is a Tuple2 and K a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Spark requires you to follow your `groupBY` with an `aggregation` method. I would have tupleRDD as a `DataFrame` like:

```
column1 column2

url_3 url_2
url_3 url_2
url_3 url_1
url_4 url_3
url_4 url_1
```

and pass on a `collect_list(column2)` like

`df.groupBy('column1').agg('column2', collect_list('column2'))`.

This example is in Python. Scala/Java APIs should be similar, though.